# What are the differences between Json.Net versions?

Tags: .net, json, windows-phone-7, json.net, xamarin.android

I am working on an android application through monodroid. I have to port over a windows phone 7 application and it uses [Json.net](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) Windows 7 Phone edition.

I am wondering what the difference between that and the regular .net 4.0 version is? Is there a version for monodroid or could I use  the regular .net 4.0 version?

It would be best if I could use the same library for both devices as then I could put it in a shared library and stop some duplicate code.

Comment: AFAIK the main difference is the build target. I assume you will need to rebuild from source when targeting monodroid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is their blog post on the Windows Phone 7 version. It explains why it's a different release, but it sounds like you could have a version which only supports the set of features that work on both platforms.

http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2011/01/03/json-net-4-0-release-1-net-4-and-windows-phone-support.aspx

Comment: Even though the project has a reference to it the part I am looking at seem to be using some built in stuff. DataContractJsonSerializer (what comes from System.Runtime.Serialization). However my android solution only seems to have 2.0.5 where I need 4.0.